# How to create index in virtual Column in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to create index in virtual column in Microsoft SQL Server 2005

```
WITH OrderedOrders AS 
(
  SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY I_D) AS RowNumber FROM ST_Agency_Tbl
  WHERE  Delete_Flag <> 1
) 
  SELECT * FROM  OrderedOrders 
   WHERE  RowNumber >= 8000000 AND RowNumber <= 8000100
```

I want to create index in RowNumber

Comment: You cannot add an index to a CTE ...

Comment: I think you need to use a temp table for this purpose

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you will be able to do it. When you create an index on a computed column, the column has to past some tests (see more on [MSDN](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189292%28v=sql.90%29.aspx)).

One of them is:

> All columns that are referenced in the expression come from the table that contains the computed column.

This is not true in your case.

Comment: Thanks for answering 
I use RowNumber as serial column 1,2,3,....
but when I execute Above query , Execution time between 2 - 3 minutes
Can I use alternative method to generate serials without using ROW_NUMBER() ?

Answer (score 0):

For this type of queries I use the following solution if the source table has a UNIQUE CLUSTERED index (on `Sales.SalesOrderHeader.SalesOrderID` column in this example):

```
-- Test #2
SELECT  SalesOrderID, RevisionNumber, OrderDate, DueDate, ShipDate, OnlineOrderFlag
FROM    Sales.SalesOrderHeader h
WHERE   h.SalesOrderID IN 
(
    SELECT  y.SalesOrderID
    FROM
    (
        SELECT  x.SalesOrderID, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY h.SalesOrderID) AS RowNum 
        FROM    Sales.SalesOrderHeader x
    ) y
    WHERE   y.RowNum BETWEEN 1001 AND 1050 
)
GO
```

For this test I used AdventureWorks2012 sample database http://msftdbprodsamples.codeplex.com/releases/view/93587.